# Using unison to sync between MacOS and debian-linux

Tags: debian, osx

I am doing a project with EV3 (Lego Mindstorms).

Currently my workflow requires saving the file, transferring it, compiling it and finally run it.

This takes too much time and I wanted to improve it.

That's why I want to use unison to allow two-way sync over my computer and the remote machine.

Now, the problem is that via `brew install unison` it installs unison 2.51.2, and via `apt-get` on the EV3DEV (debian-linux) it installs unison 2.40, which is incompatible.

Apparently 2.51.2 is unsupported for debian-linux, so this means that somehow I need to downgrade the MacOS version, problem is that brew offers only 2.51.2 .

Note: I already tried to install brew, but the brew installation `Cannot find a vendored version of ruby for your armv5tejl`.

Comment: Weclome , you can install brew on debian. [Linuxbrew](http://linuxbrew.sh/)

Comment: @GAD3R Thank you. Unfortunately I already tried to but the brew installation `Cannot find a vendored version of ruby for your armv5tejl`

Comment: As of January 19, Unison 2.51 is in **beta**. The latest stable release, which I would recommend, is 2.48. [source](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/docs.html) I think your best path would be version 2.40 on both computers. Is it possible to install an older version via Brew?